# Calculate distinct totals over time

Tags: sql

I have the following data:

```
UniqueID    SenderID    EntryID Date
1           1           1       2015-09-17
2           1           1       2015-09-23
3           2           1       2015-09-17
4           2           1       2015-09-17
5           3           1       2015-09-17
6           4           1       2015-09-19
7           3           1       2015-09-20
```

What I require is the following:

```
3   2015-09-17
4   2015-09-19
4   2015-09-20
4   2015-09-23
```

Where the first column is the total unique entries upto that date. So for example the entry on the 23/9 of Sender 1 and Entry 1 does not increase the total column because there is a duplicate from the 17/9.

How can I do this efficiently *ideally* without joining on the same table as what you end up with is a *very large* query which is not practical. I have done something similar in Postgres with OVER() but unfortunately this isn't available in this setup.

I could also do this in code - which I have but yet again it has to calculate outside of the db system and then import back in. With millions of rows this process takes days and I ideally only have hours.

Comment: *"I have done something similar in Postgres with OVER() but unfortunately this isn't available in this setup."*: You haven't provided this critical information. What database are you using? What is your setup? What are your restrictions?

Comment: Using a sub-query and an index on SenderID,EntryID is the fastest approach I can think of.

Comment: I am trying to be non DB specific as I am happy to move to a different platform if I could find a useful feature that worked!! I'm moving from MySQL to PostgreSQL for the OVER() feature but if someone said - "oh SQL server" can do it then I'd use that. Or if there is a feature of MySQL I don't know about then I'd use that. I'm not after a platform specific solution - I'm flexible.

Answer (score 1):

`OVER` is ANSI standard functionality available in most databases.  What you are counting are starts for users, and you can readily do this with a cumulative sum:

```
select startdate,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by startdate) as CumulativeUniqueCount
from (select senderid, min(date) as startdate
      from table t
      group by senderid
     ) t
group by startdate
order by startdate;
```

This should work in any database that supports window functions, such as Oracle, SQL Server 2012+, Postgres, Teradata, DB2, Hive, Redshift, to name a few.

EDIT:

You need a `left join` to get all the dates in the data:

```
select d.date,
       sum(count(d.date)) over (order by d.date) as CumulativeUniqueCount
from (select distinct date from table t) d left join
     (select senderid, min(date) as startdate
      from table t
      group by senderid
     ) t
     on t.startdate = d.date
group by d.date
order by d.date;
```

Comment: That is great and I would mark it as the answer but it only returns the first 2 rows in the desired result set rather than the 4.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Gordon Linoff for the basic query. However, it will not return rows for dates that don't increase the cumulative sum.

To get those extra rows, you need to include an additional subquery that lists all the distinct dates from the table.  And then you left join with Gordon's query + a few minor tweaks to get the desired result:

```
select d.SomeDate,
       sum(count(t.SenderId)) over (order by d.SomeDate)
from (select distinct SomeDate
        from SomeTable) d
left join (select SenderId, min(somedate) as MinDate
            from SomeTable
           group by SenderId) t
  on d.SomeDate = t.MinDate
group by d.SomeDate
order by d.SomeDate;
```